# redirected Autocomplete Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a script with autocomplete that I wanted if the user typed a word that does not have in the script it was redirected to a specific url example warning.html but I am not able to do that, if you can help me from now thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete Testt</title>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [
   {label: 'Google', value: 'http://google.com'},
   {label: 'Yahoo', value: 'http://yahoo.com'},
   {label: 'BMW', value: 'http://bmw.com'},
   {label: 'Bing', value: 'http://bing.com'}
  ];
  
     $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
   source: data,
   focus: function (event, ui) {
    $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
   },
   select: function (event, ui) {
    $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
    window.location = ui.item.value;
    return false;
   }
  });
   });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="autocomplete" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jqueryui 1.8. I am using 1.9 in the example below. Because, 1.9 has the response function, which can check the length.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete Testt</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var data = [
            {label: 'Google', value: 'http://google.com'},
            {label: 'Yahoo', value: 'http://yahoo.com'},
            {label: 'BMW', value: 'http://bmw.com'},
            {label: 'Bing', value: 'http://bing.com'}
        ];

        $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
                window.location = ui.item.value;
                return false;
            },
            response: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                console.log('action here');
            }
        }
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="autocomplete" />
</body>
</html>
```